# of the right color vs in the right color

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

Are all constructions below correct?

> - This shirt is the right color
> - This shirt is in the right color
> - This shirt is of the right color

The context may be someone saying that the color of a shirt is ideal for somebody, for a certain event, eg for a party or New Year's Eve, or that a shirt is the ideal match with other garment (eg a pair of pants).

Comment: I understand you're having trouble with prepositions, but please do try to provide more context. Why are you writing this? What are you trying to convey? Most importantly, what do you think and why? See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: @Em No problem. I have added the possible contexts in which I'd use these constructions.

Answer (score 1):

"The shirt is the right color," is your best choice.  You are merely describing the shirt.
It's much like saying, "The shirt is wet."  You are not comparing the shirt to some other object so a preposition is not necessary.

If you were shopping for shirts and you liked a certain style and asked your sales associate to show you different color of the same shirt, then you might say, "I would like to see this shirt in a different color."  Here you drawing a relationship between shirts and colors.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples are different ways of saying something is ***in the right*** color.

- That color ***matches*** your pants.
- It [the shirt] ***matches*** your pants.
- The colour of this shirt ***goes with*** your trousers. (UK)
- That color ***suits*** you and it ***goes*** really well ***with*** the pants

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-with)
>
> 3.) **[match](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/match_1#match_1__9)** [SINGULAR] a thing that forms an attractive combination with something else
>   *The curtains are a good match for the sofa*.
>
> 2.) [**[go with something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-with)**] to seem good, natural, or attractive in combination with something
>   *Which shoes go best with this dress?*
>
> 2.) **[suit](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/suit_1)** if a style or something that you wear suits you, it makes you look good
>   *Dark colours suit her best.*
>   *The new hairstyle really suits her.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the question. Perhaps the question was less clear before it was edited.

Comment: @ColinFine  the answer is right at the top in **bold**. Then, I think my motivation at the time was to provide more content,  I gave alternative versions to help future visitors and learners. Saying  a colour *matches* or *goes with* something is more common and useful to know IMO.

Answer (score -1):

None of what you posted is actually a sentence, since there is no full-stop.

I'm going to start by assuming that you meant them to be full sentences, rather than just fragments, in which case only the first one would be normal usage.

On the other hand, all three examples could easily be extended into something valid:

- "This shirt is the right colour to match my coat."
- "This shirt is in the right colour for my team."
- "This shirt is of the right colour, at last."

(I really don't like that last example, incidentally!)

Comment: I do not understand why your last example with "at last" is more correct than "This shirt is of the right colo(u)r".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista  Because is is an actual sentence, rather than an incomplete fragment.

Comment: I'll rephrase it. I don't think that adding "at last" to an "incomplete sentence" makes it complete. "at last" is just an optional adverbial expression, not a fundamental sentence component such as an object, a verb or a subject.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista  It sounds like you think that "the rules of English" govern the language, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Mike Brockington, it sounds as if you think that the trivial details of how somebody chooses to write down an utterance have something to do with the linguistic or grammatical character of that utterance, When I speak a sentence it doesn't have a full stop. If you write it down with or without a full stop, it doesn't change the grammaticality or character of my sentence.

Comment: @ColinFine  I think that punctuation isn't trivial. In this case, as I said, those words need to be treated differently if they are a fragment versus a full sentence.

Comment: OK. All three are perfectly grammatical as sentences. And in suitable context, all three could be natural as sentences, though I agree that only the first is natural without a special context.